# What are 3 notes of equal duration in a bar in 4/4 time called?

Tags: terminology

Three notes of equal duration in one beat are called triplets, but what are 3 notes of equal duration in a bar in 4/4 time called?

I wonder because these occur in the Zombies song "Tell Her No":

[image]

Comment: I just voted to migrate this to Music Practice and Performance, but the likely answer is just *tuplet* - these exists in all fractional variants.

Comment: @guidot but if any duration that is normally divided in some power of two is instead divided in three, that's a triplet, whether they are 1/3 of a 4/4 measure or 1/48 of one.  (And, as the answers have pointed out, these measures don't in fact contain three equal notes; the first two have 1.5 times the duration of the third.)  Thanks for bringing the question here.

Comment: If you want beats like this why are you in 4 time. If you want three notes of equal length why then are you not in some sort of three time?

Comment: @phoog: Good point; now that I "hear it" in my head, I see how that last note is a quarter note, but I hadn't seen it in the tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three notes of equal duration in a quarter note are called eighth-note triplets, three notes of equal duration in a half note are called quarter-note triplets and three notes of equal duration in a whole note (i.e. a bar of 4/4/ time) are called half-note triplets.

Note: the tab from your question is correct, but it doesn't show three notes of equal duration. They are not triplets.

Comment: ... we can tell *these* three notes are not of equal duration because the first two notes have dots, but the third doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

They *would* be called, as three identical things often are, triplets. In the case of three which should have been two, in a bar of 4/4, they'd be **minim triplets**.

However, they're no such things as those written here, because the first two are *dotted*, whilst the third is a simple crotchet (one quarter/ one beat) note. It's become 'popular' to write a bar as such, but the older, generally accepted way would be to write a dotted crotchet first, then a quaver tied to a crotchet, so the bar is seen to be divisible into two equal halves.

Comment: In fact, the notation shown here is older than the notation you suggest, which would never be seen in the early seventeenth century, but arose I suppose in the late 18th or early 19th century.